# What does "Gita Anvay Yog Samanvay" mean?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

What's the meaning of the phrase *Gita Anvay Yog Samanvay*? And can someone elaborate it for ease of understanding?

Comment: please cite source for the phrase where do you find it.